Stuck showing simple inequality $n^4 - 2n^2 > 3n ^ 3, n \geq 10$
I am struggling to show the following inequality,
$$n^4 - 2n^2 > 3n ^ 3$$
for $n \in \mathbb{Z}, n \geq 10$.

My (Failed) Attempt
$$\begin{align} n ^4 - 2n^2 &= n(n^3 - 2n) \\ \\ & \geq 10(n^3 - 2n) \end{align}$$
I can see that $10n^3 > 3n^3$ which is helpful towards the desired conclusion, but I don't know how to remove the $-20n$ term.

Generally for a polynomial $f(x)$ with $n$ real roots to solve $f(x)>0$ or some similar inequality, you can do casework on $x$ considering the $n+1$ intervals into which $\mathbb R$ is divided by the $n$ real roots. This is called the method of intervals, and it’s what at least one of the answer uses.

For $n\geq 10$ we have $$n^4-2n^2-3n^3=n^2(n^2-3n-2)\geq n^2(10n-3n-2)= n^2(7n-2)\geq 68n^2> 0$$
so we deduce $n^4-2n^2> 3n^3$ for $n\geq 10$, as desired.

$$n^4-2n^2>3n^3$$
$$\iff n^2(n^2-3n-2)>0$$
$$\iff n^2\left(n-\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{2}\right)\right)\left(n-\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{17}}{2}\right)\right)>0$$
$$\iff n\in\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{2},\infty\right)$$
We ignored the negative case as it is of no use for us. Now $\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{2}$ is certainty less than $10$ as $10=\frac{3+\sqrt{289}}{2}$

Hence for all $n\ge10$ this inequality is true.

Notice that $a_n=n^2-2-3n>0$ when $n>10$, this is true because this sequence is increasing and $a_{10}>0.$
($a_{n+1}-a_n=2n-2$)
$$n^4-2n^2=n^2(n^2-2)>n^2\cdot3n=3n^{3}$$

First, note that as $n \geq 10$, you only have to prove that $n^{2} > 3n + 2$ for all $n \geq 4$. This inequality is true for $n = 4$. Let us assume that the result is true for $n = k$, then $k^{2} > 3k + 2$, we have to show the result is true for $n = k+1$.
So $(k+1)^{2} = k^{2} + 2k + 1 > 5k+3 > 3k + 5 = 3(k+1)+2 ~ \forall~ k\geq 1$(by induction hypothesis). So, the result is true for all $n \geq 4$. By multiplying $n^{2}$ on both sides, we got the inequality which is true for $n \geq 4$. I don't understand why it is only asked for $n \geq 10$.
